# Can "A case in point is Japan" be use as a dependent clause of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

My sentence in full length is "A case in point is Japan, they have experienced a drop of TFR from 3.44 in 1950 to only 1.55 in 2015."

Divide the sentence by comma into two parts, I would like to know these two parts can be linked together with the first part as dependent and the second part as  independent.

Comment: A case in point is Japan: they have experienced a TFR drop from 3.44 in 1950 to only 1.55 in 2015. Use a colon, rather than a comma.

Comment: Any grammatical declarative sentence may become a complement clause by putting _that_ in front of it. However, in this sentence, the clause in question should be followed by a semicolon; this is a comma splice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> A case in point is Japan.

This is an independent clause that can function as a complete sentence. It has a subject ("a case in point"), a verb ("is"), and a complement ("Japan"). This is an S-V-C sentence. As [Jeff Blair explains ("SVC Sentence Pattern")](http://www.agu.ac.jp/%7Ejeffreyb/SVO/bs3.html), the complement describes the subject. This independent clause should be treated as such with appropriate punctuation, like a period (separating the clauses) or a colon (connecting the clauses that are directly related - see the [UNC Writing Center website for more](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/)).

If you are joining two independent clauses, you need a coordinating conjunction like "for." Alternatively, you could make one of the clauses subordinate or dependent with a subordinate conjunction. (For more details see Robin L. Simmons, "[The Coordinating Conjunction](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/coordinatingconjunction.htm)" and "[The Subordinate Conjunction](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateconjunction.htm)," Chomp Chomp). The result would look like this:

> A case in point is Japan. They have experienced ... (separate sentences)
>
> A case in point is Japan: they have experienced ... (colon joins two independent clauses)
>
> A case in point is Japan, for they have experienced ... (two independent clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction)
>
> A case in point is Japan, since they have experienced ... (an independent clause joined to a now-subordinate clause by a subordinate conjunction)

Comment: thank you, which way would you suggest?

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion either way. My own style tends towards the first and fourth, but the choice is largely up to context and style.